# How to get content between tags inside a variable in VBS

Tags: html, regex, vbscript

I have a variable filled with structured HTML content (a web site content) and I simply want to get content from a "div" called article and it looks like;

```
     <article>
html stuff here html stuff here html stuff here html stuff here
html stuff here html stuff here html stuff here html stuff here

            </article>
```

I'm trying with:

```
Dim url

url="myUrl"

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Set myDiv = New RegExp
With myDiv
    .Pattern    = "<article>.*</article>"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global     = false
End With

objXML.Open "GET", url, False
    objXML.Send("")
    html= objXML.responseText


    Set objMatch = myDiv.Execute(html)

    for each x in objMatch
        WScript.Echo objMatch.Item(0)
    next




or .Pattern    = "#<article>([^<]*)</article>#'"
or .Pattern    = "<article>([^<]*)</article>'"
```

With no luck, any suggestion?

Comment: Did you get this working? If not please let me know and I will work to get my answer updates to where it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `Regex`

```
(?<=\<article\>)([\s\S]*)(?=\<\/article>)
```

**[REGEX101](http://regex101.com/r/tI0lH5)**

**Example** (not-tested)

```
Set myDiv = New RegExp
With myDiv
    .Pattern    = "(?<=\<article\>)([\s\S]*)(?=\<\/article>)"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global     = false
End With
```

Comment: Hope you don't want to "kill" me, but how to add that option? (I'm playing with VBS in windows 7)

Comment: Tried .Singleline = True like my example?

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method :/

Comment: JavaScript and VBScript do not have an option to make the dot match line break characters. In those languages, you can use a character class such as [\s\S] to match any character. This character matches a character that is either a whitespace character (including line break characters), or a character that is not a whitespace character. Since all characters are either whitespace or non-whitespace, this character class matches any character. http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html Don't know how to implement this

Comment: @Mark, I did not know that about `VBscript` as I don't use it, and assumed it had Single-Line mode like `VB`, updated my answer to use character classes.

Comment: It works changing your pattern with:                                     .Pattern    = "(<article\>)([\s\S]*)(?=\<\/article>)"

Comment: Hmm the '(?<=\<article\>)' Positive Look-Behind should have worked, but yes it is the same as using `(<article\>)`. I get carried away with `lookarounds` I will admit, glad you got it working. @Mark